# Kotlin authentication using SQL

Tags: php, android, authentication, networking, kotlin

i looking for right way to create login system in my android app.
I already have accounts stored in mysql base on my vps.
I'm using kotlin lang and Fuel http module.
I looking for sample basic auth in kotlin and controler in PHP.
Also if you know better way to include authentication for my app tell me advice, tutorial,sample!

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "haslo";
$myDb ="users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $myDb);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

//echo "dziala";
//print_r($_POST);
}
//echo $_POST['0'];

if($_POST[0]=='aa'&&$_POST[1]=='bb'){

//echo "Zalogowano!";
}


$conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($_POST[0]=='aa'&&$_POST[1]=='bb'){
    foreach( $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $r){
    //echo $r['pid'];
    echo json_encode($r);   
    }
    }
    //$pytanie = ' where imie like("%'.$_GET[osoba].'%")';

    //$users = $mysql->wykonaj('select imie from dynamics.pracownik'.$pytanie);
        //print_r($result);
        //echo json_encode($r);

    ?>
```

Kotlin

```
fun auth(user: User){
            FuelManager.instance.baseParams = listOf("0" to user.login, "1" to user.password)
            //FuelManager.instance.baseParams = listOf("password" to "1")
            FuelManager.instance.basePath= "http://10.1.67.185/"
            "plik.php/".httpPost().responseJson() { request, response, result ->
                //make a GET to https://httpbin.org/get and do something with response
                val (data, error) = result
                if (error == null) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"It works!")
                    Log.d(TAG,"Result\n ${result.get()} \n Result")
                    Log.d(TAG,"#Response \n $response \n#Response")
                    //Log.d(TAG,"Request \n $request \n Request")
                } else {
                    //error handling
                    //Json = result.get().obj()
                    Log.d(TAG,"doesn't work")
                }
        }

        }
```

then

```
09-18 07:27:55.236 7486-7486/com.example.mkolbusz.intraservapp D/tag: Result
     com.github.kittinunf.fuel.android.core.Json@77cbb7f 
     Result
    [B@476b74c 09-18 07:27:55.238 7486-7486/com.example.mkolbusz.intraservapp D/tag: #Response 
     <-- 200 (http://10.1.67.185//plik.php/)
    Response : OK
    Length : 145
    Body : (
    {"pid":"1","name":"asdasd","price":"11.00","description":"sdafsdfsdf","created_at":"2018-09-17 11:39:12","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
    Headers : (11)
    Connection : [Keep-Alive]
    Content-Length : [145]
    Content-Type : [text/html; charset=UTF-8]
    Date : [Tue, 18 Sep 2018 07:27:55 GMT]
    Keep-Alive : [timeout=5, max=100]
    Server : [Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9]
    X-Android-Received-Millis : [1537255674903]
    X-Android-Response-Source : [NETWORK 200]
    X-Android-Selected-Protocol : [http/1.1]
    X-Android-Sent-Millis : [1537255674857]
    X-Powered-By : [PHP/7.2.9]

    #Response
```

Now idk how to get result

Comment: Hi, could you please make your question complete by posting the code you've tried so far?

Comment: There you go.
I have no idea how to parse body to object.